# Order of Destructor Calling When Leaving Scope? (C++)

Tags: c++, scope, destructor

I'm trying to understand the order of destructor calling when dropping out of scope. Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Parent{

Parent(){cout<<"parent c called \n";}
~Parent(){cout<< "parent d called \n";}
};

class Child: public parent{

Child(){cout<< "child c called \n";}
~Child(){cout<<"child d called\n";}
};
```

Now, I know that the child constructor and destructor is derived from the parent, so the following main:

```
int main(){

Parent Man;
Child Boy;

return 0;
}
```

Would produce the output:

```
parent c called
parent c called
child c called
... //Now what?
```

But now, what happens when I drop out of scope? I've got multiple things that need to be destroyed, so how does the compiler choose the order? I could have two output possibilities:

```
parent c called           |         parent c called      
parent c called           |         parent c called
child c called            |         child c called
child d called            |         parent d called
parent d called           |         child d called
parent d called           |         parent d called
```

With the left case applying if Boy is destroyed first, and the right case applying if Man is destroyed first. How does the computer decide which one is deleted first?

Comment: The order of destructor calls for automatic objects, temporary objects and members is the reverse of that of constructor calls.

Comment: Could always just run the program to find out

Comment: @EdHeal, that would be proof of nothing. A sample may falsify a statement, but never prove one.

Comment: Andrey, thank you, that's exactly what I needed to know. Ed, I did run the program and the results were consistent with Andrey's description, but I did not know what rule was enforcing it, or if it would apply in all cases. So although I did in reality know the output of this one simple example, I thought it would be the most straightforward way to get my question across.

Comment: For reference, the C++11 standard, Section 6.6, paragraph 2: `On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) that have been
constructed in that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A derived destructor is called before an ancestor destructor.  So the `Child` destructor body will be called first, then the `Parent` destructor body next.  And constructed objects are destructed in reverse order, so the `Boy` object will be destructed before the `Man` object is destructed.